# Identify if yaml key is anchor or pointer

Tags: python, yaml, ruamel.yaml

I use ruamel.yaml in order to parse YAML files and I'd like to identify if the key is the anchor itself or just a pointer. Given the following:

```yaml
foo: &some_anchor
  bar: 1

baz: *some_anchor
```

I'd like to understand that `foo` is the actual anchor and `baz` is a pointer. From what I can see, there's an `anchor` property on the node (and also `yaml_anchor` method), but both `baz` and `foo` show that their anchor is `some_anchor` - meaning that I cannot differentiate.

How can I get this info?

Comment: Is there a reason you want to differentiate? Also, what have you looked into so far?

Comment: I need to know it in order to manipulate it correctly, it's something that relates to my business logic. I have tried to see what the API offers (as I described here), but couldn't find any useful API for that.

Comment: That doesn't tell us much more unfortunately... Did you do any websearches? Have you seen [`yamlpath`](https://github.com/wwkimball/yamlpath)? It appears to be able to [select anchors and aliases](https://github.com/wwkimball/yamlpath/wiki/Segment:-Anchors), perhaps that's helpful? As it is actually based on `ruamel.yaml`, you might find in the sourcecode how the identify anchors.

Answer (score 1):

Since PyYaml and Ruamel.yaml load an alias node as a reference of the object loaded from the corresponding anchor node, you can traverse an object tree and check if each node is a reference of a previous visited object or not.

The following is a simple example only checking dictionaries.

```
from ruamel.yaml import YAML

root = YAML().load('''
foo: &some_anchor
  bar: 1

baz: *some_anchor
''')
dict_ids = set()
def visit(parent):
    if isinstance(parent, dict):
        i = id(parent)
        print(parent, ', is_alias:', i in dict_ids)
        dict_ids.add(i)
        for k, v in parent.items():
            visit(v)
    elif isinstance(parent, list):
        for e in parent:
            visit(e)
visit(root)
```

This will output the following.

```
ordereddict([('foo', ordereddict([('bar', 1)])), ('baz', ordereddict([('bar', 1)]))]) , is_alias: False
ordereddict([('bar', 1)]) , is_alias: False
ordereddict([('bar', 1)]) , is_alias: True
```

Comment: I think this gives false information about simple scalars being an alias in PyYAML. If you load the YAML document `{a: 1, b: 1}` into `data`, then `id(data['a'])` equals `id(data['b'])`, although there was no anchor or alias in the original document to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

In your example `&some_anchor` is the anchor for the single element mapping `bar: 1` and
`*some_anchor` is the alias. Writing the "`foo` is the actual anchor and `baz` is pointer`" is
in IMO both incorrect terminology and confusing keys with their (anchored/aliased) values. If you had a YAML document:

```
- 3
- 5
- 9
- &some_anchor
  bar: 1
- 42
- *some_anchor
```

would you actually say, probably after carefully counting,
that '`4` is the anchor and `6` is the pointer`(or`3`and`5` depending on
where you start counting)?

If you want to test if a *key* of a dict has a *value* that was an anchored node in YAML, or if that
*value* was an aliased node, you'll have to look at the value, and you'll find that they are the same Python data structure
for keys `foo` resp. `baz`.
What determines on dumping, which key's value gets the anchor and which key's (or keys') value(s) are dumped as an alias,
is entirely determined
by which gets dumped first, as the YAML specification stats that an anchor has to come before its use as an alias (an
anchor can come after an alias if it is re-defined).

As @relent95 describes you should recursively walk over the
data structure you loaded (to see which key gets there first) and in both `ruamel.yaml` and `PyYAML` look at the `id()`.
But for PyYAML that only works for complex data (dict, list, objects) as it throws away anchoring information and will
not find the same `id()` on e.g. an anchored integer value.

The alternative to using the `id` is to look at the actual anchor name that `ruamel.yaml` stores in attribute/property `anchor`.
If you know up front that your YAML document is as simple as your example ( anchored/aliased nodes are values for
the root level mapping ) you can do:

```py
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

yaml_str = """\
foo: &some_anchor
  bar: 1

baz: *some_anchor
oof: 42
"""

def is_keys_value_anchor(key, data, verbose=0):
    anchor_found = set()
    for k, v in data.items():
        res = None
        try:
            anchor = v.anchor.value
            if anchor is not None:
                res = anchor not in anchor_found
                anchor_found.add(anchor)
        except AttributeError:
            pass
        if k == key:
            break
    if verbose > 0:
        print(f'key "{key}" {res}')
    return res
    
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
data = yaml.load(yaml_str)
is_keys_value_anchor('foo', data, verbose=1)
is_keys_value_anchor('baz', data, verbose=1)
is_keys_value_anchor('oof', data, verbose=1)
```

which gives:

```
key "foo" True
key "baz" False
key "oof" None
```

But this in ineffecient for root mappings with lots of keys, and won't find anchors/aliases that were nested deeply
in the document. A more generic approach is to recursively walk the data structure once and create dict with
as key the anchor used, and as value a list of "paths", A path itself being a list of keys/indices with which
which you can traverse the data structure starting at the root. The first path in the list being the anchor, the rest aliases:

```py
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

yaml_str = """\
foo: &some_anchor
  - bar: 1
  - klm: &anchored_num 42

baz:
    xyz:
    - *some_anchor
oof: [1, 2, c: 13, magic: [*anchored_num]]
"""

def find_anchor_alias_paths(data, path=None, res=None):
    def check_add_anchor(d, path, anchors):
        # returns False when an alias is found, to prevent recursing into a node twice.
        try:
            anchor = d.anchor.value
            if anchor is not None:
                tmp = anchors.setdefault(anchor, [])
                tmp.append(path)
                return len(tmp) == 1
        except AttributeError:
            pass
        return True

    if path is None:
        path = []
    if res is None:
        res = {}
    if isinstance(data, dict):
        for k, v in data.items():
            next_path = path.copy()
            next_path.append(k)
            if check_add_anchor(v, next_path, res):
                find_anchor_alias_paths(v, next_path, res)
    elif isinstance(data, list):
        for idx, elem in enumerate(data):
            next_path = path.copy()
            next_path.append(idx)
            if check_add_anchor(elem, next_path, res):
                find_anchor_alias_paths(elem, next_path, res)
    return res


yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
data = yaml.load(yaml_str)
anchor_alias_paths = find_anchor_alias_paths(data)
for anchor, paths in anchor_alias_paths.items():
    print(f'anchor: "{anchor}", anchor_path: {paths[0]}, alias_path(s): {paths[1:]}')
print('value for last anchor/alias found', data.mlget(paths[-1], list_ok=True))
```

which gives:

```
anchor: "some_anchor", anchor_path: ['foo'], alias_path(s): [['baz', 'xyz', 0]]
anchor: "anchored_num", anchor_path: ['foo', 1, 'klm'], alias_path(s): [['oof', 3, 'magic', 0]]
value for last anchor/alias found 42
```

You can then test your the paths you are interested in against the values returned by `find_anchor_alias_paths`,
or the key against the final elements of such paths.